# is ther way to expose aws public alb without putting 0.0.0.0 in ingress rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, aws-security-group, aws-application-load-balancer

I have aws application load balancer which is of type external and in public subnet. The targets ec2 are in private subnets.
The ALB subnets are whitelisted in palo alto firewall software. We have 0.0.0.0 in ngress rule of the ALB security group.

Is there a way to allow all public internet traffic without providing  0.0.0.0/0 in the ingress rule of alb ?  any additional servers or provide only palo alto subnets in sSG groups ?

Comment: What is a "palo alto subnet"? What do you mean by "whitelisted in palo alto firewall software"? This is not a standard AWS offering. How/where is it configured? Please Edit your question to provide these additional details. Also, please tell us _why_ you do not want the Security Group to permit access from `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein its for audit compliance request on if this can be done

Comment: I don't understand too. You have a application that you want to expose to the whole internet but can't set it to `0.0.0./0` due to "compliance"?

Comment: Weird but true. Just checking any options avaialble

Comment: Your compliance team are saying "Don't open stuff to the world", but your requirement is to "Open stuff to the world". This is not a technical problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to allow all public internet traffic without providing 0.0.0.0/0 in the ingress rule of the ALB?

No, to allow ***public*** internet traffic, you need to give ***public** access*.

You don't know anyone's IP on the internet so you need to specify all IPs using `0.0.0.0/0`.